# Convergent sub-martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I have this problem. Suppose $(X_t)_{t\geq 1}$ is a sequence of random variables with values in $[0,\infty)$. I know that $E(X_t)\rightarrow 1$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ and $(\exp(X_t))_{t\geq 1}$ is a sub-martingale. I would like to find whether $\sup_t E(\exp(X_t))<\infty$ in order to apply the martingale convergence theorem. Do you have any idea if this is possible/not feasible?

Thanks!

Comment: Jensen's inequality gives $$\mathbb E\left[e^{X_t}\right]\geqslant e^{\mathbb E[X_t]}. $$

Comment: yes but this does not help in finding whether $\sup_tE(\exp(X_t))<\infty$. Do you have any idea if there is somehow a way to show this?

Comment: You can not control $E[exp(X_t)]$ as it could explode (it's easy to find a counter example). Therefore you should look for other way for proving the convergence of the exponential sub-martingale.

Comment: I hoped there was some kind of result linking the two :) Thanks!